# Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item?

Tags: errors, missing

This message appears when I add a new centered section at the end of the file. The line with the error is marked by astherisks. Here's my whole code file:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Tema 1}

\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\normalfont}

\rfoot{Pág. \thepage \hspace{1pt} de \pageref{LastPage}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}

\line(1,0){300} \\
[0,25in]
\huge{\bfseries Tema 1.\\ La Constitución Española de 1978. Características. Los principios constitucionales y los valores superiores. Derechos y deberes fundamentales. Su garantía y suspensión.} \\
[2mm]
\line(1,0){200}

\end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\clearpage\mbox{}\clearpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\setcounter{page}{1}

\begin{center}

\section{Título preliminar}

\end{center}

\vspace{5mm}

\textbf{Art. 1}

\vspace{3mm}

\begin{enumerate}

\item España se constituye en un Estado social y democrático de Derecho, que propugna como valores superiores de su ordenamiento jurídico la libertad, la justicia, la igualdad y el pluralismo político.

\item La soberanía nacional reside en el pueblo español, del que emanan los poderes del Estado.

\item La forma política del Estado español es la Monarquía parlamentaria.

\end{enumerate}

\vspace{5mm}

\textbf{Art. 2}

\vspace{3mm}

La Constitución se fundamenta en la indisoluble unidad de la Nación española, patria común e indivisible de todos los españoles, y reconoce y garantiza el derecho a la autonomía de las nacionalidades y regiones que la integran y la solidaridad entre todas ellas.

\vspace{7mm}

\textbf{Art. 3}

\begin{enumerate}

\item El castellano es la lengua española oficial del Estado. Todos los españoles tienen el deber de conocerla y el derecho a usarla.

\item Las demás lenguas españolas serán también oficiales en las respectivas Comunidades Autónomas de acuerdo con sus Estatutos.

\item La riqueza de las distintas modalidades lingüísticas de España es un patrimonio cultural que será objeto de especial respeto y protección.

\end{enumerate}

\vspace{5mm}

\textbf{Art. 4}

\begin{enumerate}

\item La bandera de España está formada por tres franjas horizontales, roja, amarilla y roja, siendo la amarilla de doble anchura que cada una de las rojas.

\item Los Estatutos podrán reconocer banderas y enseñas propias de las Comunidades Autónomas. Estas se utilizarán junto a la bandera de España en sus edificios públicos y en sus actos oficiales.

\end{enumerate}

\vspace{5mm}

\textbf{Art. 5}

\vspace{3mm}

La capital del Estado es la villa de Madrid.

\clearpage

\textbf{Art. 6}

\vspace{3mm}

Los partidos políticos expresan el pluralismo político, concurren a la formación y manifestación de la voluntad popular y son instrumento fundamental para la participación política. Su creación y el ejercicio de su actividad son libres dentro del respeto a la Constitución y a la ley. Su estructura interna y funcionamiento deberán ser democráticos.

\vspace{7mm}

\textbf{Art. 7}

\vspace{3mm}

Los sindicatos de trabajadores y las asociaciones empresariales contribuyen a la defensa y promoción de los intereses económicos y sociales que les son propios. Su creación y el ejercicio de su actividad son libres dentro del respeto a la Constitución y a la ley. Su estructura interna y funcionamiento deberán ser democráticos.

\vspace{7mm}

\textbf{Art. 8}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Las Fuerzas Armadas, constituidas por el Ejército de Tierra, la Armada y el Ejército del Aire, tienen como misión garantizar la soberanía e independencia de España, defender su integridad territorial y el ordenamiento constitucional.

\item Una ley orgánica regulará las bases de la organización militar conforme a los principios de la presente Constitución.

\end{enumerate}

\vspace{5mm}

\textbf{Art. 9}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Los ciudadanos y los poderes públicos están sujetos a la Constitución y al resto del ordenamiento jurídico.

\item Corresponde a los poderes públicos promover las condiciones para que la libertad y la igualdad del individuo y de los grupos en que se integra sean reales y efectivas; remover los obstáculos que impidan o dificulten su plenitud y facilitar la participación de todos los ciudadanos en la vida política, económica, cultural y social.

\item La Constitución garantiza el principio de legalidad, la jerarquía normativa, la publicidad de las normas, la irretroactividad de las disposiciones sancionadoras no favorables o restrictivas de derechos individuales, la seguridad jurídica, la responsabilidad y la interdicción de la arbitrariedad de los poderes públicos.

\end{enumerate}

\clearpage

\begin{center}

\section[Título I: De los derechos y deberes fundamentales]{Título I}
\vspace{-3mm}
\subsection*{De los derechos y deberes fundamentales}

\end{center}

\vspace{5mm}

\textbf{Art. 10}

\vspace{3mm}

\begin{enumerate}

\item La dignidad de la persona, los derechos inviolables que le son inherentes, el libre desarrollo de la personalidad, el respeto a la ley y a los derechos de los demás son fundamento del orden político y de la paz social.

\item Las normas relativas a los derechos fundamentales y a las libertades que la Constitución reconoce se interpretarán de conformidad con la Declaración Universal de Derechos Humanos y los tratados y acuerdos internacionales sobre las mismas materias ratificados por España.

\end{enumerate}

\begin{center}

\section*{Capítulo Primero}
\vspace{-3mm}
\subsection*{De los españoles y los extranjeros}

\end{center}

\vspace{5mm}

\textbf{Art. 11}

\vspace{3mm}

\begin{enumerate}

\item La nacionalidad española se adquiere, se conserva y se pierde de acuerdo con lo establecido por la ley.

\item Ningún español de origen podrá ser privado de su nacionalidad.

\item El Estado podrá concertar tratados de doble nacionalidad con los países iberoamericanos o con aquellos que hayan tenido o tengan una particular vinculación con España. En estos mismos países, aun cuando no reconozcan a sus ciudadanos un derecho recíproco, podrán naturalizarse los españoles sin perder su nacionalidad de origen.

\end{enumerate}

\vspace{5mm}

\textbf{Art. 12}

\vspace{3mm}

Los españoles son mayores de edad a los 18 años.

\vspace{7mm}

\textbf{Art. 13}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Los extranjeros gozarán en España de las libertades públicas que garantiza el presente Título en los términos que establezcan los tratados y la ley.

\item Solamente los españoles serán titulares de los derechos reconocidos en el artículo 23, salvo lo que, atendiendo a criterios de reciprocidad, pueda establecerse por tratado o ley para el derecho de sufragio activo y pasivo en las elecciones municipales.

\item La extradición sólo se concederá en cumplimiento de un tratado o de la ley, atendiendo al principio de reciprocidad. Quedan excluidos de la extradición los delitos políticos, no considerándose como tales los actos de terrorismo.

\item La ley establecerá los términos en que los ciudadanos de otros países y los apátridas podrán gozar del derecho de asilo en España.

\end{enumerate}

\begin{center}

\section*{Capítulo Segundo}
\vspace{-3mm}
\subsection*{Derechos y libertades}

\end{center}

\vspace{5mm}

\textbf{Art. 14}

\vspace{3mm}

Los españoles son iguales ante la ley, sin que pueda prevalecer discriminación alguna por razón de nacimiento, raza, sexo, religión, opinión o cualquier otra condición o circunstancia personal o social.

\begin{center}

\section{}

**\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I'm sure that there is no missing \item, and I cannot add more sections to my table of contents because of it. Where is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can't put `\section` inside `\begin{center}`...`\end{center}`.

Comment: I would use the package `titlesec`, it provides a lot of macros for controlling headings and titles, even locally: you just define the new section formatting before using it (or paragraph, chapter, &c) and implement it. A good companion is titletoc, that allows you to control how a table of contents is formatted: https://ctan.org/search/?phrase=titlesec

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to

```
\begin{center}

\section*{Capítulo Segundo}
\vspace{-3mm}
\subsection*{Derechos y libertades}

\end{center}
```

You should never have a section heading inside `center` ((nor should you ever need explicit `\vspace`)

You could remove the error by removing the `center` environment or (if you must) adding some text to the subsection, this has no error

```
\begin{center}

\section*{Capítulo Segundo}
\vspace{-3mm}
\subsection*{Derechos y libertades}
zzzz
\end{center}
```

But even though it does not generate an error it is still incorrect markup.

Comment: I've solved the problem. Not followiing your advice, but thanks anyway.

I've changed \begin{center} - \end{center} with \begin{centering} - \end{centering}, and no more errors in that part of the code.

Comment: @icg837 `\begin{centering}` is even more wrong! `\centering` is the the command form and `\begin{center}` is the display environment form. You just get lucky that you avoid an error by using `\centering` here, The _whole point_ of latex is that you use logical commands like `\section` and then specify _once_ at the start of the document how sections are displayed. So you should have no formatting or spacing commands at the section headings in the document.